# Как работает команда `nginx` если её нет в $PATH?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

$ whereis -b nginx
nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/lib/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx
```

Исполняемый файл находится здесь: `/usr/sbin/nginx`, но `/usr/sbin` нет в $PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

от имени «рядового» пользователя:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

от имени пользователя с идентификатором 0 (обычно у него имя `root`):

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

---

как видите, во втором случае в переменной окружения `PATH` присутствует каталог `/usr/sbin`.

поэтому команда `nginx`, выполненная от имени «рядового» пользователя, не приведёт к запуску программы `nginx` из файла `/usr/sbin/nginx`. а от имени пользователя с именем `root` — приведёт.

---

дополнение из комментариев:

> А как же рядовой пользователь запускает nginx -t для проверки корректности конфига? При этом проверка работает как от root'а, так и от рядового пользователя (разве может ругнуться на SSL сертификат). Не знаю, что там в дебианах, но в центосе спокойно можно запустить (я правда не обращал внимания на PATH)

либо этот пользователь указывает всё-таки полный путь к файлу, либо переменная окружения `PATH` (хотя бы в момент выполнения команды) содержит путь к этому файлу, либо запускается какой-то другой файл, расположенный не в каталоге `/usr/sbin`, либо запускается функция/псевдоним оболочки (которая впоследствии запускает файл уже по абсолютному пути).

---

доп. чтение.

- механизм поиска и выполнения программ описан в [стандарте posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01)
- к сожалению, стандарт posix не содержит каких-либо указаний по поводу функционального распределения файлов/каталогам по файловой системе. поэтому надо смотреть в документацию соответствующих реализаций стандарта:

  - [unix и наследники](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem#Conventional_directory_layout)
  - [gnu/linux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FHS)

Comment: А как же рядовой пользователь запускает `nginx -t` для проверки корректности конфига? При этом проверка работает как от root'а, так и от рядового пользователя (разве может ругнуться на SSL сертификат). Не знаю, что там в дебианах, но в центосе спокойно можно запустить (я правда не обращал внимания на PATH)

Comment: @AK `$ nginx -t` > `-bash: nginx: command not found`

Comment: Магии нет: в центос nginx лежит в /usr/sbin и этот путь есть в PATH рядового пользователя.